# How to Plot Multiple Vertical Lines From File?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been trying to use matplotlib to add vertical lines to my plot and then add fill between them.

- thresh_f is the name of the file
- thresh_f has two columns only

The code below will have errors when the file has more than one line

```
start, end = np.loadtxt(thresh_f, usecols = [0,1], unpack = True)
ax.axvspan(start, end, alpha=0.3, color='y')
```

I get the error:

> 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'

I have zero clue to understandwhat that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your variables `start` and `end` become arrays when file has more then one lines. You have to improve your code like:

```
start, end = np.loadtxt(thresh_f, usecols = [0,1], unpack = True)
ax = plt.gca()
print (start, end) # test data [ 0.  5.] [ 1.  6.]
# check the type of start variable
# loadtxt may return np.ndarray variable
if type(start) is list or type(start) is tuple or type(start) is np.ndarray:
    for s, e in zip(start, end):
        ax.axvspan(s, e, alpha=0.3, color='y')   # many rows, iterate over start and end
else:
    ax.axvspan(start, end, alpha=0.3, color='y') # single line

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ah thank you so much. Works perfectly. Thank you for explaining the reason why! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the `if`-`else` statement, you can pass `ndmin = 2` to `np.loadtext()`. This assures that your `start` and `end` are always iterable.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt. subplots(1,1)

thresh_f = 'thresh_f.txt'
starts, ends = np.loadtxt(thresh_f, usecols = [0,1], unpack = True, ndmin = 2)

for start, end in zip(starts, ends):
    ax.axvspan(start, end, alpha=0.3, color='y')

plt.show()
```

Here the results for one and two lines of text:

[image]
[image]